# Why calling method for two times result in TypeError: object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x

Define two class based on `BaseHandler` as below:

```
class BaseHandler:
    def successor(self, successor):
        self.successor = successor

class ScoreHandler1(BaseHandler):
    pass

class ScoreHandler2(BaseHandler):
    pass
```

Initialize two instances:

```
h1 = ScoreHandler1()
h2 = ScoreHandler2()
```

Call successor method first time :

```
h1.successor(h2)
```

Now call it second time:

```
h1.successor(h2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'ScoreHandler2' object is not callable
```

Why can't call the method more times?

```
callable(ScoreHandler2)
True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you call `h1.successor(h2)`, you're calling the *method* named "successor". Inside this method, you set the *attribute* named "successor" to the object `h2`.

The second time you call `h1.successor(h2)`, you're calling the *attribute* named "successor", which you defined previously to `h2`. Since `ScoreHandler2` does not implement `__call__`, it'll raise an error.

To fix this, avoid naming attributes with the same name as methods.

Comment: It is no-relation with `__call__`.

Comment: callable(ScoreHandler2)

Comment: Output is : True

Comment: Yes, it's no-relation with `__call__`, it's relation with you naming the attribute "successor" with the same name as the method "successor". I've explained that in my answer.

Comment: `callable(ScoreHandler2)` returns True because it's a class and it has a constructor. Now check if `callable(h2)` (with `h2` being an instance of ScoreHandler2) is True.